# Comparing one array against another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, api, comparison, gmail

I am using the 'contacts' gem in rails to retrieve a users contacts from their mail application.  It returns the contacts like so:

```
["person name", "personemail@example.com"], ["person name", "personemail@example.com"], ["person name", "personemail@example.com"] etc...
```

I want to compare this list to the Users already signed up for my site

Users.find(:all) returns:

```
[#<User id: 11, login: "examplelogin", email: "example@example.com">, #<User id: 12, login: "examplelogin", email: "example@example.com">, etc... ]
```

What is the best way to go about comparing the gmail contact emails to the User emails and displaying only the ones that are a match?

I was thinking something like:

```
@contacts = Contacts::Gmail[params[:from]].new(params[:login], params[:password]).contacts
@contacts.each do |c|
  @email = c[1]
  @user = Users.find_by_email(@email)
end
```

Which would presumably only return the users where there was a match.  I feel like there must be a better way to go about this that I am not considering.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@users = Users.find_all_by_email(@contacts.collect{|contact| contact[1]})
```

edit:

What you had before would perform a find for each contact and leave you only with the result of the last query, either a user or not depending on whether one existed with this email. This performs one query and returns an array of all successful matches:

```
where 'users'.'email' in array_of_email_addresses.
```

Comment: worked like a charm! is this just a shorthand way of doing what i described above?